# How can I read the routing table information from Kernel space?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I would like to be able to read the routing table from kernel space...

In user space, this information is readable in /proc/net/route, but I don't know how to read the same information from kernel space..

I don't want to modify, only read..

any ideas?

Comment: There are network namespaces...Maybe you want to get same result as `ip route get` does ? also you may look to netlink code. Accessing /proc for routing information is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the routing table, you would need to send a message of type `RTM_GETROUTE` to the kernel using a socket of the `AF_NETLINK` family — this is the [rtnetlink(7) interface](https://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/7/rtnetlink.htm).

For convenience, rather than sending messages over a socket, you can use the [libnetlink(3) library](https://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/3/libnetlink.htm), and call `int rtnl_wilddump_request(struct rtnl_handle *rth, int family, RTM_GETROUTE)`.

For an even simpler cross-platform abstraction, you could use the [libdnet library](http://libdnet.sourceforge.net), which has a function `int route_get(route_t *r, struct route_entry *entry)`.

Answer (score -1):

You may find out where in kernel source code tree this file is created in '/proc' pseoudo filesystem by searching the "route" keyword or "create_proc_... smth" Take a look at how such files are created for your kernel in source.

I suspect it's located somewhere in net/ipv4/route.c